# Is there a 'best practice/intended' way for using Material-UI for their components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've gone through their documentation, and I cannot for the life of me find out the 'best practice/intended' way of using Material-UI for web development with react. What I mean is, what is the common convention for using `<div>` or `<section>/<article>/<aside>`? Do you use `<Grid>` or `<Container> / <Box>` elements, and set the component to whatever I want it? Do I just mix in vanilla JSX/HTML and only use the Mui components when they're needed? Thank you for any/all guidance!